# Virtual function breaking private access

Tags: c++, virtual

I recently came across this article on [IBM site](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr134.htm). Below is the sample code

```
#include "iostream"

class B {
public:
  virtual void f()
  {
    std::cout<<"\n In class B";
  }
};

class D : public B {
private:
    int i;

  void f()
  {
  std::cout<<"\n In class D i = "<<i;
  }
  public:
    D(int i_num):i(i_num)
    {}
};

int main() {
  D dobj(10);
  B* bptr = &dobj;
  D* dptr = &dobj;

  // valid, virtual B::f() is public,
  // D::f() is called
  bptr->f();

  // error, D::f() is private
  //dptr->f();
}
```

We are now able to call private function of D.I wanted to know doesn't this break C++ encapsulation ?

P.S. : Please go to Virtual function access section in Virtual function. I do not know why I am not getting exact link when I do paste.

Comment: I suppose this is the equivalent of explicitly implementing an interface in C#. And instead of breaking encapsulation perhaps you are strengthening it. But, yes I guess it is a bit confusing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Public virtual function derived private in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061726/public-virtual-function-derived-private-in-c)

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484592/overriding-public-virtual-functions-with-private-functions-in-c

Comment: hi Mat, Will appreciate if you can tell me some tips to find duplicate questions.

Comment: @user258367: When you type the question, use proper keywords as lookup list of probable matches appears based on what you type. Open the relevant ones and see if it is similar to your question. Other way is to use google, ex: This Q of yours can be searched in google by searching keywords: `virtual + private + access + site:stackoverflow.com` it gives results specific to stackoverflow.com..Hth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access-specifiers are compile-time construct, and so, the compiler detects any violation of access-rules at compile-time (obviously) based on the *static* type of the object  (or pointer). Such violation cannot be detected at runtime.

So `bptr->f()` works, because the compiler sees that the *static* type of `bptr` is `B` which has a `public` function `f()` defined, so the expression `bptr->f()` passes the compiler's test. Hence it works.

But `dptr->f()` doesn't work, since the *static* type of `dptr` is `D` which has a private function `f()`, hence the code wouldn't even compile!

Now whether it breaks encapsulation or not, is a very subjective question and will receive subjective answers. It entirely depends on how one defines it and the arguments directly flows from it. There is no one universal definition. My personal opinion is, if the language allows it, then (it would imply that) according to the C++ community, it doesn't break encapsulation, or if it does, then C++ allows it so as to achieve something very nobel (which otherwise isn't possible). Otherwise, I would say its just yet another misfeature of C++ just like the following:

[Default argument in the middle of parameter list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637679/default-argument-in-the-middle-of-parameter-list)

Answer (score 6):

The call `bptr->f()` is evaluated at run time depending on the type of objected pointed by `bptr`. At compile time the compile sees the `bptr->f()` call as call to `B::f()` and since `B::f()` is `public` the compiler doesn't report only error. It is only at runtime that actual function call `D::f()` is evaluated.

This doesn't break the `Encapsulation` principle this is a feature of C++ called `Run-time Polymorphism` or `Dynamic Polymorphism`

You cannot directly call `dptr->f()` because `D::f()` is declared under `Private` Access specifier and You cannot access privately declared members from outside the class.

Answer (score 2):

It is by design.

**B::f** is public. User access of **f** via a pointer to **B** is allowed. Since **f** is virtual, the call would be dispatched to derived classes' **f**.

But **D::f** is private, you can't access **f** via a pointer do **D**.